# Counting occurrences of rows that have 3 column values the same MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers, count, where-clause, sql-insert

MySQL `BEFORE INSERT` trigger

I have a `bookings` table. I have 3 columns called

```
facility_id, booking_date, time_slot
```

I also have another table called `facility` with a column called `facility_id`.
They are linked by `WHERE bookings.faciliy_id = facility.facility_id`

I am trying to count the occurrence of when the 3 columns in the bookings table are repeated, i.e.:

```
1, 2017-02-02,08:00
1, 2017-02-02,08:00
```

I would expect this to be 2.

I then am trying to check this result to see if its >= to the facility_capacity which is stored in the facility table. Throw an error message if true.

```sql
DELIMITER
//
 CREATE TRIGGER facility_full BEFORE INSERT ON bookings
    FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN 
        SELECT DISTINCT facility_id, booking_date, timeslot, COUNT(*) FROM bookings 
        SET COUNT = Answer
            IF (Answer) >=  facility_capacity
            THEN  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Facility Full';
            WHERE bookings.facility_id = facility.facility_id;
            END IF;
    END 
 //
 DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you said  count the occurrence of when the 3 columns in the bookings table are repeated. here is one way to solve your problem.

```
DELIMITER
//
 CREATE TRIGGER facility_full BEFORE INSERT ON bookings
    FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN 
        DECLARE v_count int;
        Declare msg TEXT;
        DECLARE v_facility_capacity  int;


        select count(*) into v_count from bookings where facility_id = New.facility_id and booking_date  = new.booking_date  and time_slot = new.time_slot;

select facility_capacity  into v_facility_capacity from facility 
where facility.facility_id = New.facility_id;

            IF (v_count) >=  v_facility_capacity  THEN
            set msg = concat('MyTriggerError: Facility Full: ', cast(new.facility_id as char));
            signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = msg;
            END IF;
    END 
 //
 DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks, Where would i insert the WHERE Clause as i need to take the facility capacity from the facility's table. (i.e WHERE bookings.facility_id = facility_facility_id)